# Why is iTunes account showing up in system services but I don't have an account

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-data

I don't have a iTunes account.

Why is iTunes account showing up using cellular data in the system services view of used data?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What are you trying to do? Remove the account? Also, what sequence of taps in the settings app are you using to define "system services".

Comment: System services is under privacy in cell data in settings. I don't have an account so I'm wondering why my phone is using it. It's used more data than anything. Jus wondering why it's there

Comment: I have everything iTunes turned off but it's still using data

Answer (score 1):

Go to iTunes and App Store in settings app and turn off "use cellular data".

The App Store use is bundled with iTunes use in that category.